# Logout fails with Prestashop on Nginx Server, SEOfriendly URLs and multilingual Shop

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop, multilingual

hope someone can help me with that. Strangly (after days of searching the net for a solution) I guess there are not too many people having the same issue I have.

My Prestashop 1.6.1.4 runs on a Nginx Server 1.8

I have the following Nginx configuration

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid     /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;


http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush  on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and additional I have the project rewrite rules as prestashop documenation recommends

like this

```
location / {
  index /index.php;

  rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine with this, just only it is not possible for a customer to log out, by clicking the related button.

I found out that this problem come sonly if I have more than 1 language activated, because the url that is called by the link works like the

http://example.com/de/?mylogout=

this fails

but when I call

http://example.com/?mylogout=

without the language code inside the url the logout works. This problem won't come with the shop installed on a Apache Server.

So I guess this might be solved with a proper rewrite directive for Nginx.

Is there anyone familiar with Prestashop and Nginx to help me with that?